# True efficiency of an ordinary photovoltaic cell

Tags: energy, photons, antimatter, solar-cells

While learning about antimatter and the conservation of energy, I found that fission reactions convert about 0.1% of mass into energy, fusion reactions convert about 0.7%. I also found a similar percentage for fossil fuels.

While trying to find an analogy for solar cells I find values calculated from other parameters such as the panel size, etc., which give an average percentage of about 20%, which is absolutely not the percentage I'm looking for (for example, the efficiency percentage for fossil fuels when calculated in a similar manner is about 40%, and for fission around 37%).

I know a chemical reaction is different from the photoelectric effect. I know a single photon doesn't have mass. I calculated the energy of a 500nm photon to be around 4x10⁻¹⁹J, I'm just trying to know which percentage of its energy would be converted to (electric?) energy when using the photoelectric effect inside the photovoltaic cell. Something general, I know there are differences between home project cells and high end cells. Just want to know the efficiency of the whole process (and I know it's not 20%).

I'm just trying to compare how efficient a matter-antimatter interaction is compared to out current methods of energy production. But I lack the math and physics knowledge to get me any further.

Comment: A certain amount of energy comes from the sky from the sun. A solar panel illuminated by this energy produces a certain amount of electrical output. Why do you think the appropriate conversion efficiency from sunlight to electricity can't be 20%?

Comment: @JonCuster Would it be safe to assume that the output energy would then be 20% of 4x10⁻¹⁹J, so 8x10⁻²⁰? I know there is an energy output formula for the photoelectric effect utilizing plank length and the photon wavelength, this number using 20% doesn't make much sense to me, but maybe you know something I don't. I would like the answers to include a calculation, I'm giving a wavelength example.

Comment: The output of a given single photon above bandgap is somewhere between nothing and one electron-hole pair that makes it out of the panel.

Comment: Also remember that the typical radiant energy from the Sun impinging on 1 square meter (in most optimum latitude) is quoted as 1000 watts, a given photovoltaic cell excepts energy from a much more narrow band of frequencies than those added up to that 1000 watts.  Therefore, there is efficiency of transition of photon energy to electrical energy but there is also a huge loss due to photons that carry energy and are not even involved in the process -- their efficiency obviously zero.

Comment: @K7PEH A bigger effect is that the cell voltage is only half a volt, but the photocurrent is due to photons with energies greater than about 1 electron volt. Regardless of photon energy, you only capture about half an eV per photon as electricity.

Comment: I'm not sure what you are after, but a good start is looking at the quantum efficiency: Quantum efficiency - Wikipedia https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quantum_efficiency

Comment: @StevanV.Saban Thank you so much for taking the time to try to understand, you provided the best answer actually. If you want to include it as an actual answer to the post I will tag it as the best answer. Thank you again!

Comment: Glad I could help. :-)

Comment: Please do not add meta-commentary to your posts, and especially do not add rude commentary to your posts.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you are looking for is quantum efficiency.  This is copied directly from Wikipedia;

[image]

*A graph showing variation of internal quantum efficiency, external quantum efficiency, and reflectance with wavelength of a crystalline silicon solar cell*

A solar cell's quantum efficiency value indicates the amount of current that the cell will produce when irradiated by photons of a particular wavelength. If the cell's quantum efficiency is integrated over the whole solar electromagnetic spectrum, one can evaluate the amount of current that the cell will produce when exposed to sunlight. The ratio between this energy-production value and the highest possible energy-production value for the cell (i.e., if the QE were 100% over the whole spectrum) gives the cell's overall energy conversion efficiency value. Note that in the event of multiple exciton generation (MEG), quantum efficiencies of greater than 100% may be achieved since the incident photons have more than twice the band gap energy and can create two or more electron-hole pairs per incident photon.

Comment: Note: This answer was copied directly from Wikipedia.

Comment: Quantum efficiency - Wikipedia https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quantum_efficiency

Comment: Quantum efficiency is (electrons out)/(photons in). It's not energy efficiency: the electron energy is lower than the photon energy.

Comment: @JohnDoty Good point. I was thinking photon energy in vs electrical energy out.  I think this part of the OP is where I misundetstood: "I'm just trying to know which percentage of its [photon]energy would be converted to (electric?) energy when using the photoelectric effect inside the photovoltaic cell"

Answer (score 1):

Solar panel efficiency is the ratio of electrical power output to optical power input. A 1 $m^2$ panel typically intercepts about 1 kW of sunlight on a sunny day, and if it has 20% efficiency it will produce 200 W of electrical power.

Since we lack the technology to extract useful energy from matter-antimatter interaction, it is impossible to assign an efficiency to that.

Comment: **Comments have been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/148312/discussion-on-answer-by-john-doty-true-efficiency-of-an-ordinary-photovoltaic-ce); please do not continue the discussion here.** Before posting a comment below this one, please review the [purposes of comments](/help/privileges/comment). Comments that do not request clarification or suggest improvements usually belong as an [answer](/help/how-to-answer), on [meta], or in [chat]. Comments continuing discussion may be removed.